# How to use DRF Custom serializer field with DB model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using relation database which is having Binary Field, So how can I use DRF serializer  to save the field value

I have referred the documentation https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields
and understood some of the part and created below, but I'm not sure how to use it in serializer

Model

```py
class MyData(models.Model):
    data = models.BinaryField()
```

Custom Field

```py
class BinaryField(serializers.Field):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value.decode('utf-8')

    def to_internal_value(self, value):
         return value.encode('utf-8')
```

But how should I use this in my below serializer

```py
class BlobDataSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyData
        fields = ('id', 'data')
```

So basically I'm trying to store incoming data in binary field. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
class BlobDataSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyData
        fields = ('id', 'data')

    data = BinaryField()
```

For a more reusable solution, you could also subclass ModelSerializer and customize the `serializer_field_mapping`.

See https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-field-mappings

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I see this if I add new field in serializer then its working fine. but if field is existing in model (e.g. data) and for same I have to apply BinaryField , its not working. So how can I apply for the existing model field

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, could you post some code and where it's going wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry , there was issue in my code. It worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What about using [Serializer Method Field](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

```py
class BlobDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    data = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_data(self, obj):
        return obj.decode('utf-8')

    class Meta:
        model = MyData
        fields = ('id', 'data')
```

Comment: SerializerMethodFields are readonly, so if you want to be able to edit the data field, you should create a custom field.

Answer (score 0):

## Explicitly per field

In the serializer, specify the field type for each custom field.

```
class BlobDataSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyData
        fields = ('id', 'data')

    data = BinaryField()
```

## Implicitly for all fields

For a more reusable solution, you could also subclass ModelSerializer and customize the `serializer_field_mapping`.

Because we need to override a class variable (not an instance variable), it's not as straightforward as the above solution and it's also kind of "magical".

```
class BlobDataSerializerMetaClass(type(serializers.ModelSerializer)):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, attrs):
        # Call the __new__ method from the ModelSerializer metaclass
        super_new = super().__new__(cls, clsname, bases, attrs)
        # Modify class variable "serializer_field_mapping"
        # serializer_field_mapping: model field -> serializer field
        super_new.serializer_field_mapping[models.BinaryField] = BinaryField
        return super_new

# Set the above metaclass as the serializer metaclass    
class BlobDataSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer, metaclass=BlobDataSerializerMetaClass):
    class Meta:
        model = MyData
        fields = ('id', 'data')
```

See https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-field-mappings

Comment: I couldn't edit @Nico Griffioen's answer because the "edit queue" was full so I posted a standalone answer instead.