# Add Binary data into django rest framework API

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, django-rest-framework

**model.py**

```
class TblSnapshot(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    snapshot = models.BinaryField()
```

I want to add Binary Data in API, but it's generating error

```
TypeError at /api
__str__ returned non-string (type memoryview)
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback and the code for your serializer?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to implement a custom field ([as per here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57920730/how-to-use-drf-custom-serializer-field-with-db-model). This is how your serializer would look for such model

```
class BinaryField(serializers.Field):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value.decode('utf-8')

    def to_internal_value(self, value):
        return value.encode('utf-8')

class TblSnapshotSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TblSnapshot
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'snapshot')

    snapshot = BinaryField()
```

Comment: it's giving error of 'Tblsnapshot' object has no attribute 'decode' @Jura- brazdil

Comment: Seems like the serializer gets a whole TblSnapshot objects into its snapshot field. It's tblsnapshot.snapshot that is the binary value and has the decode method.

Can you post your view?

Comment: actually I am using primary key of Tblsnapshot from another table as a foreign key